# Filter to a specific date within a specific column

Tags: r, date, time, dplyr

I have a dataframe, df with column DateTimeUTC.

```
                         ID              DateTimeUTC

                         A               12/4/2019 11:30:30 PM
                         A               12/4/2019 11:30:30 PM
                         B               12/5/2019 11:30:30 PM
                         B               12/5/2019 11:30:30 PM
                         B               12/5/2019 11:30:30 PM
```

I would like to filter, so that DateTimeUTC only displays dates from 12/5/2019, with this outcome:

```
                           ID              DateTimeUTC


                         B               12/5/2019 11:30:30 PM
                         B               12/5/2019 11:30:30 PM
                         B               12/5/2019 11:30:30 PM
```

I have tried this command, but have not been successful:

```
                       library('dplyr')
                       library('lubridate')

                       data %>%  filter as.Date(DateTimeUTC == "2019-12-05")
```

I would like ALL days of 12/5/2019, including the times (hours, min and secs)
Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, the 'DateTimeUTC' is in a different format.  Convert the column to DateTime class (it seems that the format is month-day-year-hour-minute-second), and remove the time with `as.Date`, then do the comparison (`==`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
data %>%
     filter(as.Date(mdy_hms(DateTimeUTC)) ==   "2019-12-05")
#  ID           DateTimeUTC
#1  B 12/5/2019 11:30:30 PM
#2  B 12/5/2019 11:30:30 PM
#3  B 12/5/2019 11:30:30 PM
```

---

In the OP's code, the `as.Date` is applied on a logical vector which would be anyway `FALSE` because it is comparing the original format with a different format and this would result in failure of executing the code i.e.

```
"12/4/2019 11:30:30 PM" == "2019-12-05"
#[1] FALSE
```

Wrapping `as.Date` on this would result in an error

```
as.Date("12/4/2019 11:30:30 PM" == "2019-12-05")
```

> Error in as.Date.default("12/4/2019 11:30:30 PM" == "2019-12-05") :
>   do not know how to convert '"12/4/2019 11:30:30 PM" == "2019-12-05"'
>   to class “Date”

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), 
   DateTimeUTC = c("12/4/2019 11:30:30 PM", 
"12/4/2019 11:30:30 PM", "12/5/2019 11:30:30 PM", "12/5/2019 11:30:30 PM", 
"12/5/2019 11:30:30 PM")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Yes, I tried to accept, but it not let me. I had to 'wait' a certain time period. Thank you

Comment: @akrun, how would I filter if there are two columns that contain dates. Ex. starttime column and endtime column

Comment: @TanishaHudson  I  would convert both the 'starttime' and 'endtime' to `DateTime' class as showed here and then use in `filter` i.e. `data %>% filter(as.Date(mdy_hms(starttime)) >=   "2019-12-05" &  as.Date(mdy_hms(endtime)) <=  "2020-12-05")`